IIS - Url Rewrite and subfolers
I'm new to URL Rewrite so any help is appreciated.
my current situation is that I have a subdomain set up that is currently being rewritten to point to an internal server (reverse proxy). This works fine and dandy.
The issue is when I try to access subfolders.
For example, www.website.com returns the appropriate default document, but www.website.com/subfolder/doc.html still returns the default document from www.website.com
Below is the contents of the web.config file for the site. I made this using the directions from an article on mircrosoft's website.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.1.12:8081/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://www.website.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CustomAnchorHref" preCondition="ResponseIsAnything">
                    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="href=(.*?)http://192.168.1.12:8081/(.*?)\s" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="href={R:1}https://www.website.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CustomFormAction" preCondition="ResponseIsAnything">
                    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="action=(.*?)http://192.168.1.12:8081/(.*?)\\" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="action={R:1}https://www.website.com/{R:2}\" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsAnything">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/(.+)" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.1.12:8081/" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="eee" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

As always, Any help is appreciated.
(if it makes any difference this is on an older server running IIS 8)

What do you want www.website.com/subfolder/doc.html to return? You can try to use failed request tracing to view the detailed process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

so www.website.com rewrites to our internal server:8080
I'd like www.website.com/subfolder/doc.html to return server:8080/subfolder/doc.html
right now it's returning server:8080/default.html

You can refer to this rule:
<rule name="test">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^website.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="rewrite" url="server:8080/{R:1}" />
</rule>

